# yajra datatables invalid json response

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatable, datatables

I am using [InfyOmLabs-laravel-generator](https://github.com/InfyOmLabs/laravel-generator)  for my project.

that helps me to generate my datatables and it using [yajra-laravel-datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables).

but i have a problem :

my code working on my local machine but when i put my project in the server, all my datatables encounter an error, Invalid JSON response!

i checked my response, it is an html response -_- , but every thing working on local . help me.

here is an example of my code : router + controller + dataTable

in web.php

[request route of admins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJCbS.png)

in controller

[controller of admins using **AdminDataTable** in index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zPDwK.png)

in AdminDataTable

[html builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk6H6.png)

[dataTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0L4U.png)

I realized that request pass these two condition in DataTable.php in render function ( only in server - in local is ok ).

[render in DataTable.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkYiX.png)

why?!

Comment: Please don't include code as image, prefer copy/paste

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajax or postAjax in your dataTable and it gonna work!